# How to resolve Rails ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, database-migration

When I try to load a page of my site, I get:

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending.
>   To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

But when I when I run `rake db:migrate` I get:

> SQLite3::SQLException table "options" already exists...

Running `rake db:reset` doesn't fix anything either. Trying to load a page still gives me the PendingMigrationError.

If instead I run `rake db: drop` and then `rake db:migrate`, I get this:

> rake aborted
>   Standard Error! An error has occured, this and all later migrations canceled.
>
> undefined method 'can_pick_many_options' ....

Note: I'm running Rails 4.1.2

Comment: You should read a little on migrations. Anyhow, there is a folder in your app root, `db/migrations`. There are all the migration files you've created. Go through them and see if you are creating table `options` twice. If you do, delete the "bad" file and keep the good one...

Comment: In `db/migrate`, there's 4 files, 1 for each table. One of the files has code that indeed creates the option table, but I don't see why this should break anything, because the every other file has code that creates its respective table.I suspect this had something to do with something that I did earlier, when I dropped a table (named "choices"), and then created the one named "options". I don't understand where I went wrong though.

Comment: After you've dropped your database, try `bin/rake db:create` before running `bin/rake db:migrate`. Note that in Rails 4.1 you should be prefixing your `rake` and `rails` commands with `bin/` to take advantage of Spring (if you're using it). Otherwise you should be prefixing them with `bundle exec` to make sure you're using the version referenced in your `Gemfile` - if not you might run into issues like your `undefined method` error.

Comment: I will also add that migrations can become tricky if you go and mess around with them after they've been migrated. In general you should create a *new* migration for any permanent changes to your database schema (including dropping tables). However if you do decide to modify or delete an existing migration, it should be rolled back first (`bin/rake db:rollback`), because if you try it afterwards you won't be able to. Maybe not a big deal if you are able to drop the database, but it is if you want to retain any data. Also remember to use `bin/rake db:migrate:status` to check migration status.

Comment: 1) I don't know what Spring is. I don't know if I'm using it.
2) I dropped the database because I'm still in dev mode; I haven't released the site/app yet, so I figured it'd just delete the table and start anew. I'm fine with deleting the entire database at this point. I just want to stop get past this error.
3) Is there some way to derive the database and migrations from the schema? That seems more straight-forward.
4) trying `bin/rake` just gives an "bin is not recognized as an internal or external command..." error

Comment: 1) [Spring](http://github.com/rails/spring) is included by default in Rails 4.1.
2) That's fine. Did you try those commands with `bin/` prefixed? If it still doesn't work I'm not sure where `can_pick_many_options` is coming from unless it's a method you're calling in the migration itself.
3) You can use `bin/rake db:schema:load`, which loads your overall schema from `db/schema.rb`. It doesn't regenerate your individual migrations, but it is itself basically a migration. It's regenerated directly from the database when you run the migration task successfully, or `bin/rake db:schema:dump`.

Comment: 1) `can_pick_many_options` is a variable that I defined.
2) I fixed all the problems by deleting the migrations.
Thanks for all the help and suggestions anyways.

Comment: Make sure you have a `schema.rb` backed up somewhere in that case (e.g. in a git commit), because if you accidentally run a new migration on an empty database before loading your schema, it's gonna get overwritten and you'll lose all your previous changes.